# Caret package findCorrelation() function

Tags: r, correlation, r-caret

Hello I am having trouble with the **findCorrelation()** function, Here is my input and the output:

```
findCorrelation(train, cutoff = .50, verbose = FALSE)
```

> Error in findCorrelation_exact(x = x, cutoff = cutoff, verbose =
>   verbose) :    correlation matrix is not symmetric

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 17):

the findCorrelation function expects a correlation matrix as x value, so try this instead:

```
findCorrelation(cor(train), cutoff = .50, verbose = FALSE)
```

Reference: [Caret pre-processing](https://topepo.github.io/caret/preprocess.html)

Comment: I tend to agree 

Answer (score 4):

Well, it happens because the matrix possibly does not have as many columns as rows (or vice versa). E.g.

```
library(caret)
train <- cor(mtcars)
findCorrelation(train, cutoff = .50, verbose = FALSE)
# works
findCorrelation(train[, -1], cutoff = .50, verbose = FALSE)
# Error in findCorrelation_exact(x = x, cutoff = cutoff, verbose = verbose) : 
#   correlation matrix is not symmetric
dim(train[, -1])
# [1] 11 10
```

(At least that would be my guess according to the error message.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a data frame then you may have to make it into a matrix first.

`corval <- findCorrelation(cor(as.matrix(train)), cutoff = 0.80, verbose = FALSE, names = FALSE)`